# Backtest not showing any results for a SMA crossover script in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, moving-average, crossover

Trying below script in Pine Script version 5. No errors in scripts. But, it doesn't show any results in backtest. Can anyone please help?

`code`
**bold**
*italic*

> quote
> ****//@version=5

```
strategy(shorttitle='Long on MA Crossover',title='Long Strategy with MA Crossover', overlay=true, initial_capital = 20000, currency = currency.USD, process_orders_on_close=true, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, default_qty_value = 20000, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.075)


//Backtest dates
fromMonth = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "From Month",  minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromDay   = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "From Day",    minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromYear  = input.int(defval = 2019, title = "From Year",   minval = 1970)
thruMonth = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "Thru Month",  minval = 1, maxval = 12)
thruDay   = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "Thru Day",    minval = 1, maxval = 31)
thruYear  = input.int(defval = 2112, title = "Thru Year",   minval = 1970)

showDate  = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show Date Range")

start     = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)        // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(thruYear, thruMonth, thruDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false       // create function "within window of time"

len1 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="MA1")
len2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="MA2")
len3 = input.int(100, minval=1, title="MA3")
len4 = input.int(200, minval=1, title="MA4")

ma1 = ta.sma(close, len1)
ma2 = ta.sma(close, len2)
ma3 = ta.sma(close, len3)
ma4 = ta.sma(close, len4)

Take_profit= ((input (3))/100)

longTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + Take_profit)

closeLong = close > longTakeProfit or ta.crossover(ma2,ma1)

//Entry 
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, limit=close[1], when = ta.crossover(ma1,ma2) and ma2 > ma3 and ma3 > ma4 and window())

//Exit
strategy.close("sell", when = closeLong and window())****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is in the last line , `strategy.close("sell", when = closeLong and window())`
when you use the `strategy.close()` function then you have to provide the same trade id as in the `strategy.entry()` function , you have placed a unknown id "sell" which is never used to enter any trade with this ID.
The following is the updated code and working code.

```
//@version=5
strategy(shorttitle='Long on MA Crossover',title='Long Strategy with MA Crossover', overlay=true, initial_capital = 20000, currency = currency.USD, process_orders_on_close=true, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, default_qty_value = 20000, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.075)


//Backtest dates
fromMonth = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "From Month",  minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromDay   = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "From Day",    minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromYear  = input.int(defval = 2019, title = "From Year",   minval = 1970)
thruMonth = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "Thru Month",  minval = 1, maxval = 12)
thruDay   = input.int(defval = 1,    title = "Thru Day",    minval = 1, maxval = 31)
thruYear  = input.int(defval = 2112, title = "Thru Year",   minval = 1970)

showDate  = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show Date Range")

start     = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)        // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(thruYear, thruMonth, thruDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false       // create function "within window of time"

len1 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="MA1")
len2 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="MA2")
len3 = input.int(100, minval=1, title="MA3")
len4 = input.int(200, minval=1, title="MA4")

ma1 = ta.sma(close, len1)
ma2 = ta.sma(close, len2)
ma3 = ta.sma(close, len3)
ma4 = ta.sma(close, len4)

Take_profit= ((input (3))/100)

longTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + Take_profit)

closeLong = close > longTakeProfit or ta.crossover(ma2,ma1)

//Entry 
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, limit=close[1], when = ta.crossover(ma1,ma2) and ma2 > ma3 and ma3 > ma4 and window())

//Exit
strategy.close("buy", when = closeLong and window())
```

Comment: Thanks so much @badshah_e_alam!!

Comment: welcome :-) , ;-)